# MassTransit saga persistance with Entity Framework and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, masstransit, automatonymous

I am developing a saga using MassTransit (with RabbitMQ) and Automatonymous. I am using EntityFramework as my store engine and MySQL as my database. The combination of EF and MySQL is throwing an exception every time I try to run the saga and store its state in the database. The problem is reproducible with [this](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ShoppingWeb) sample application and using a connection string to a MySQL database. The exact exception that is thrown is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Ve rify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> Syste
>   m.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find
>   the file specified  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTra
>   nsientFaultHandling)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConn ection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOption s userOptions)  at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)  at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)  at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptio ns
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)  at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)  at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, Db
>   ConnectionInternal& connection)  at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions use rOptions)  at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)  at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String
>   createDatabaseScript)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
>   connection)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
>   internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext
>   objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext
>   c)  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput
>   input)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action)  at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() 
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)  at
>   MassTransit.EntityFrameworkIntegration.Saga.EntityFrameworkSagaRepository`1.d__8`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  at
>   MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.QuerySagaFilter`2.>-Send>d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  at
>   MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.QuerySagaFilter`2.<MassTransit-Pipeline-IFilter<MassTransit-ConsumeContext<TMessage>>-Send>d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  at
>   MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.CorrelationIdMessageFilter`1.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  at
>   MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.TeeConsumeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<Send>b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  at
>   MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.TeeConsumeFilter`1.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  at
>   MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.MessageConsumeFilter`1.<MassTransit-Pipeline-IFilter<MassTransit-ConsumeContext>-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  at
>   MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.MessageConsumeFilter`1.-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  at
>   MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)  at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  at
>   MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.RescueReceiveContextFilter`1.-Send>d__5.MoveNext()
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error
>   Number:2,State:0,Class:20

If I use the local DB installed with VS 2015 instead of MySQL, then it works perfectly fine. It also works fine with the in-memory store. Even though the exception says that the server cannot be found, I can confirm that it exists and it is reachable, because the sample application does a check first when selecting the connection string and that succeeds:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // It worked, we can save this as our connection string
    return connectionString;
}
```

Is the problem caused maybe because it is trying to access the MySQL database with an SqlClient?

I am using MySQL Server 5.7, EF 6.1.3, MassTransit 3.5.7 and Automatonymous 3.5.11.

Comment: What is the exact exception?

Comment: I updated the question with the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a MassTransit question but Entity Framework question. It should be like:

How to use Entity Framework with MySQL.

You exception clearly says: `System.Data.SqlClient` is throwing it. This is the SQL Server client. It also says:

> Could not open a connection to SQL Server

You can refer to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) on how to configure EF and MySQL. In general, you need to install the `MySql.Data.Entity` NuGet package and tell EF that you are using MySQL, then configure the correct connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********"/>
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
            type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: After editing the app.config as suggested, I still needed to change the sample code. Instead of passing the connection string to the constructor of the SagaDbContext class, I had to pass the name of the connection string ("MyContext"). Then it did indeed establish a connection with my MySQL database. At that point I got another exception complaining that the table where the saga state should be stored did not exist. So in order to get the saga fully working I had to add a DbContext class and a migration to create the table in the database, otherwise MassTransit would not create it by itself.

Comment: I see. This might be caused by the EF API change since `SagaDbContext` implements all constructors of the `DbContext` base class and the only one that gets the connection string, uses the name of the connection string. https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Persistence/MassTransit.EntityFrameworkIntegration/SagaDbContext.cs#L36